# Community Promotion Ads - 2012

Tags: discussion, community-ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community Promotion Ads - 2013](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/863/community-promotion-ads-2013)

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources for the mathematically inclined
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/577).

Answer (score 21):

[image: Browse through our unanswered questions!]

Comment: P.S. I'll update this ad every week with the (then) current unanswered question count.

Answer (score 17):

[image: Try the StackExchange image uploader for Mathematica]

Answer (score 16):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: 'tis a nice looking badge, but I'm curious as to why Twitter's policies would require such a thing.

Comment: Not sure really, but I interpreted "Don't: Use any other marks or logos to represent our brand." and the Red icon under their name (see their page at http://twitter.com/logo) as meaning "don't use the word Twitter". Perhaps I'm wrong... :)

Comment: @Shog9 Perhaps not policies exactly, but from their [blog](http://blog.twitter.com/2012/06/taking-flight-twitterbird.html): *Starting today you’ll begin to notice a simplified Twitter bird. From now on, this bird will be the universally recognizable symbol of Twitter. (Twitter is the bird, the bird is Twitter.) There’s no longer a need for text, bubbled typefaces, or a lowercase “t” to represent Twitter.*

Answer (score 12):

[image: Mathematica 9 is released - try it for free]

Answer (score 12):

[image: Mathematica Experts Live: New in Mathematica 9]

Answer (score 11):

[image: Mathematica Day Berlin 2013]

Answer (score 10):

[image: Academia Stack Exchange]

Comment: Hi MMA friends! Academia.SE has a nicely growing community discussing all sorts of matters relating to academic life, from grad student to emeritus professor… I'm sure it is of interest to part of the Mathematica.SE community!

Comment: AFAIK in Plato's Greece books weren't used. Ask someone whe went to Uni

Comment: @belisarius someone’s gotta tell [Raphael](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_School_of_Athens) that this photo of his I used was badly photoshopped, then :)

Comment: Then I better shut up :)

Comment: Hey! Someone down and at the right is holding a terrestrial globe!

Comment: Here http://i.stack.imgur.com/HyeB0.png

Comment: @belisarius at the bottom right, they're working on a black iPad with a wooden frame, too! (and slightly up from the iPad, there's a woman with a head in place of knee)

Comment: Are you suggesting that time traveling was already known in the XVI century, or that Apple real owners are the Medici?

Comment: From Wikipedia "The sphericity of the Earth was established by Greek astronomy in the 3rd century BC, and the earliest terrestrial globe appeared from that period"