# 10,000 questions - should we celebrate?

Tags: discussion

On current question rates, we will cross the 10,000-question mark later this week. Should we celebrate?

Ideas include:

- An answering party, to get answers to some of the lingering [unanswered questions](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/903/unanswered-questions) answered (or closed, if that's what they deserve)
- Some sort of "fun" question, like the [confetti](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1900/8) and the [happy prime](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7132/8) question.
- A chat event

Comment: It's a nice idea, but we crossed that mark long ago if you count the deleted questions.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard That's true, but I think it would be nice to mark one of them, and we didn't mark the earlier milestone.

Comment: It's 10k questions already? brb, gotta delete some Qs that @belisarius answered... :P

Comment: @rm-rf You don't need to hurry. Your work is almost done

Answer (score 13):

This question has gotten quite a few votes, but no actual responses to my suggested events.

By my calculations, our 10,000th non-closed question will happen early the day after tomorrow (it being Wednesday here in Australia), on Friday 13th - We are currently at 9946 and running at around 30 questions / day.

So I am going to propose a Friday 13th hectohectoparty consisting of

1. A combination answering-and-chat party in the main room
2. Encouragement of fun questions on the themes of 10,000, spookiness (it being Friday 13th) and/or celebration.

Assuming this proposal gets enough support, I'll look into how to set up a chat event.

**EDIT**:

> Coming up on the Community Bulletin, starting midnight UTC Friday 13th, chat event and answering party in the main Mathematica.SE chat room!

Comment: It figures; this will probably be the first day in 126 that I am not around.

Comment: What about a Myria-party - although hecto as in hectoliter does certainly evoke partyish associations :-)

Comment: @YvesKlett - how did I miss that Myriad = 10,000? Google failed me. I'll make "hecto-hecto" the subtitle somehow.

Comment: Unfortunately, we've passed 1,000 unanswered questions. So, ironically, it will probably work out that, when we reach 10,000 questions, we will also have an unanswered questions list exceeding 10% of the total. All the more reason to get to work on the unanswered questions on Friday.

Comment: I see two instances of the even in the community bulletin.  Did you add it twice by accident? http://i.stack.imgur.com/mogws.png

Comment: Not by accident - one was a "community bulletin" and one was the chat event. I left it for the time being but can remove the one that isn't a chat event now.